# REST how to name queue resource

Tags: api, rest

I'm implementing Asynchronous REST API where file is posted and then it's added to queue for further processing. My questions is what's the best practice in this case of naming the resources.

Resource #1 POST Files where {type} is dynamic.

```
POST /files/{type}
```

Posting data to this resource. It's queued and user will receive unique Queue ID. How should the resource of files queue be named ?

Resource #2. GET files queue

OPTION 1. `GET /files/queues/{QueueID}`

OR

OPTION 2. `GET /files/{type}/queues/{QueueID}`

Which one makes more sense ? User can upload files with different {type}.

OR should I just use completely different resource of Getting queue items like:

```
GET /queues
```

AND

```
/queues/{QueueID}
```

Thanks for tips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your needs. (Or the client's needs)

I would go with the "/queues/{QueueID}" option, since the queueId itself (without the type) identifies the file, so there is no need to include it.
Additionally I would omit the {type} variable even from the POST method, because you can simply send that information in the HTTP header. (Content-Type)

The "files/{type}" approach is more useful, when you have to display the files grouped by type. Without that need, there is no need to further complicate the resource identifier.

(Note: If the "queue" and "file" items are the same, then you could use GET /files/{QueueId} )

Comment: Thanks, I think the separate resource /queues/{QueueID} in this case is clear solution. Additionally maybe I can return also header `Location: /queues/{QueueID}` for `POST /files/{type}` -Request.